# Trying to print the picturebox content but it shows there's no content

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I am trying to print the content of picturebox in which the barcode is generated. Barcode is there and when I click 'print' the print preview shows there's no content.

Print button is named 'druk', picturebox 'box4'.

Code below:

```
private void druk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            printDocument1.OriginAtMargins = true;
            printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
        }
        private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(box4.Image, 0, 0);
        }

        private void box4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
```

Comment: Looks right. Does the DrawImage line ever get hit? Is the Image really there?

Comment: Yes, the image is there, however I was wondering, the image in the picturebox is called bitmap, whereas here in print code, it is called image. I will try to change it to bitmap, maybe it will help

Comment: Does the DrawImage line ever get hit?

Comment: Yes, cause the image gets generated and it appears in picturebox but weird thing is that print preview does not display any content....

Comment: That is not what I meant. Does the line in the `printDocument1_PrintPage` get hit? Set a breakpoint on it and test it!

Comment: It gets hit but not at the correct moment. When I close the preview window, it then goes to printer selection and that's were the code gets hit. It won't print since there's no content to print.

Comment: MAkes no sense. Maybe things are hooked up wrong.